# How to use Snap.svg with Angular v4.0 (error: circle is not a function)

Tags: angular, snap.svg

I don't know how to use Snap.svg with Angular v4.0, so I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46385528/10167337) post. I tried the solution of @moeabdol (`npm install` ..., `scripts:` ..., `declare` ..., `s.circle(...)`), but I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: s.circle is not a function

However, I can load an external SVG with `Snap.load(...)`.

Why is `s.circle` not working for me?

Comment: What is 's' here, has it been defined anywhere ?

Comment: 's' is : const s = Snap('#my-svg'); you can read the code by reading the linked post.

Comment: Maybe you need to include more of your code rather than seeing the linked code.

Comment: Sorry @Ian to not include more of my code. I tried, but I had a lot of problem with stackoverflow which refused the format of my post. I'm novice, I didn't know how my post could be ok so I removed the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you draw on a `svg` and not a `div`. I made this mistake too.

In your HTML:

`<svg id="editor-canvas"></svg>`

In your component: 

`const s = Snap("#editor-canvas");
const c = s.circle(100, 100, 100);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sadzeih. With svg and not div it's work fine !

Comment: This works in Quasar/Vue as well. Need to put this inside `mounted` function instead of `created` otherwise the same error is given ` "TypeError: Cannot read property 'circle' of null"`